# Enlace de css con html

Tags: html, css

Al hacer el enlace de css con html con el atributo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylelivesti.css">
```

No me funciona y no se porque

*AQUÍ ESTA LA CAPTURA DE DONDE ESTAN LOS ARCHIVOS*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***-ARCHIVO HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="livesti.css">
    <title>LIVESTI</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="button">
        <li><a href="#">LIVESTI</a></li>
        <Li><a href="#">NOSOTROS</a></Li>
        <li><a href="#">PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES</a></li>
        <Li><a href="#">CONTACTANOS</a></Li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

***-ARCHIVO CSS:***

```
#button{
  padding: o;
}
#button li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: La imagen esta mal subida

Comment: Cuida la inserción de imágenes, estaba mal subida. Y, para código no hace falta capturas de imagen, es mejor que pegues el texto directamente porque es más fácil de analizar y de reproducir que una imagen. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y cambia la imagen por el texto del código. Lo que sí sería interesante ver es una captura de tu estructura de directorios/archivos, parece que no estás indicando bien la ruta del archivo `.css`

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que tu archivo de estilos se llama `stylelivesti.css` y tiene la extensión de archivo .css. Lo que tienes que hacer es escribir `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelivesti.css.css">` o cambiar el nombre del archivo de estilos por otro.

Quedo atento a tus inquietudes.

Comment: No entiendo, dónde ves el .css.css ?? Revisando el historial de la pregunta no veo esa referencia.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Mira atentamente a la captura de sublime text antes publicada. Si miras la parte superior izquierda, después del archivo html abierto, está el archivo css respectivo.

Comment: Ciero, buen detalle!

Comment: Ya envié la carpeta donde tengo los archivos.Espero me puedan ayudar por favor

Comment: @ValentinaTorres Si mi respuesta no te sirvió, puedes intentar escribir <link rel="stylesheet" href="./"> e ir buscando el archivo respectivo. Igual, recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta que te sea útil o aclarar tus inquietudes en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el .css duplicado, le puedes quitar el .css sobrante para que se  quede stylelivesti.css, el tuyo pone stylelivesti.css.css

Y si no funciona asi, enseñanos donde estan los archivos

Comment: ya envie donde estan los archivos

Comment: Ya envié la carpeta donde tengo los archivos.Espero me puedan ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

en la carpeta tu fichero .css no tiene extensión “.css” y sin embargo en la etiqueta link llamas a un fichero “livesti.css” que no te va a encontrar al no tener la extensión css en el explorador de archivos.